# Lotus Domino Designer 8.5 Web Preview Port Number 

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Is it possible to change the port number and host in Designer 8.5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prior to Domino Designer 8.5.3, the answer is no.

In 8.5.3, IBM implemented a setting in the Domino Designer pane of the Preferences dialog.

See [here](http://www.xpagedeveloper.com/2011/domino-web-preview) for more info.